# Epoch Unix Time Missing Few hours when the year is before 1970

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, epoch

I have a web service which returns date of birth of people. The issue that I am having is when the year of birth is around 1899 the time looses few hours. However, the more close it gets to 1970 it gets accurate. There are no issues when the birth year is after 1970.

Passed date    - 1899-12-31 16:00:00 +0000

Returning date - 1899-12-31 22:55:25 +0000  (added time difference of +0800)

after 1970 is fine]

Passed date    - 1990-08-24 16:00:00 +0000

Returning date - 1990-08-25 00:00:00 +0000

Im using objective c

jsonDateString is the passing string

```
 double dateNumber = [[jsonDateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPosition, 1)] isEqualToString:@"-"] ? - [[jsonDateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPosition + 1, 13)] doubleValue] :  [[jsonDateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPosition, 13)] doubleValue];

        NSTimeInterval unixTime = dateNumber / 1000; //WCF will send 13 digit-long value for the time interval since 1970 (millisecond precision) whereas iOS works with 10 digit-long values (second precision), hence the divide by 1000
    //    time changes***** - by ashan
        NSDate *gmtDate  = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTime]dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
        NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:gmtDate];
        NSDate *localDate = [gmtDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneOffset];
```

JsonString  - /Date(-2209017600000+0800)/

dividedby1000 : -2209017600.000000

Passed date    - 1899-12-31 16:00:00 +0000

Returning date - 1899-12-31 22:55:25 +0000

[image]

As you can see even you convert time stamp and it says 1600 and +8 would 0000. How ever it shows 1100h. Is it a issue with the epoch unix timing before 1970 or db issue on the server side.

Comment: How big is the integer you are using to store the date?

Comment: What is you divide by `1000.0` instead of `1000`?

Comment: can it be caused by the leap years prior to 1970 @Droppy

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so.  Please post the numbers you are getting back from the server for the example dates you give.

Comment: Well that number is right according to [this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/).  So what do you mean by "passed date" and "returned date"?  These are the dates in the request and response, respectively, right?

Comment: well the passed date is the unix time stamp which i receive. and return date is the date thing which i add local time zone difference - @Droppy

Comment: I think there might be a bug on that site with the way the timezone is calculated. Could you please check currentmillis.com/?-1293868800000 ? What's the timezone at the bottom for you? Perhaps in the screenshot daylight savings are not taken into account (or wrongly taken into account). It looks a lot like a bug that in a timezone listed as GMT+8 only 7 hours are added to GMT time.